# Bloc Library state

Tags: flutter, dart

In my simple app, I am using Bloc Library. 
To load data from firestore i am using stream. Problem is  when I navigate to another page or return back my data doesnt display, need to use hot reload. Its look like nn HomeScreen `BlocProvider.of<DataBloc>(context)..add(LoadData());` this event works at once.  How to solve it?

Main widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => DataBloc(),
    ),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: HomeScreenTest(),
  ),
 );
}
```

HomeScreen.

```
class HomeScreenTest extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BlocProvider.of<DataBloc>(context)..add(LoadData());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade600,
      body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
             BlocBuilder<DataBloc, DataState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is DataLoadedState) {
                      return dataColumn(context, state.dataTest);
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        }
      }
```

Bloc.

```
 class DataBloc extends Bloc<DataEvent, DataState> {

  StreamSubscription streamSubscription;

  @override
  DataState get initialState => DataState();

  @override
  Stream<DataState> mapEventToState(DataEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoadData) {
      streamSubscription = Data().dataTest.listen(
          (data) => add(DataLoaded(dataTest: data)));
    } else if (event is DataLoaded) {
      yield DataLoadedState(
          dataTest: event.dataTest);
    }
  } 
}
```

Event.

```
abstract class DataEvent extends Equatable {
 const DataEvent();
}

class LoadData extends DataEvent {
  List<DataTest> dataTest;
  LoadData({this.dataTest});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [dataTest];
}

class DataLoaded extends DataEvent {
  List<DataTest> dataTest;
  DataLoaded({this.dataTest});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [dataTest];
}
```

State.

```
class DataState extends Equatable {   
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}


class DataLoadedState extends DataState {
  List<DataTest> dataTest;
  DataLoadedState({this.dataTest});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [dataTest];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your code like this:

```
class HomeScreenTest extends StatelessWidget {
  List<DataTest> dataTest = [];
 @override
 void initState(){
   BlocProvider.of<DataBloc>(context)..add(LoadData());
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade600,
      body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
             BlocBuilder<DataBloc, DataState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is DataLoadedState) {
                      dataTest =state.dataTest;
                    }
                    return dataTest.isEmpty 
                      ? Container()
                      : dataColumn(context, state.dataTest);
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        }
      }
```